# CakePHP routing to controller and page

Tags: cakephp-2.0, cakephp-routing

Is it possible to identify a controller and pagename in the same url

`Router::connect('/:controller/');
Router::connect('/:pagename/', array('controller' => 'home','action'=>'index'));`

www.example.com/controller
so that the controller goes to the :controller/index

www.example.com/pagename
so that the page goes to home/index

Answer (score 0):

Its really confusing what really you wants. If a url ends with `:controller` like `www.example.com/posts` its generally map `index` action. Now if the url ends with pagename, means action, like `www.example.com/mypage`, you can map that as-

```
Router::connect('/mypage', array('controller' => 'homes', 'action' => 'index'));
```

So when a user browse `www.example.com/mypage`, it will map to HomesController and index action.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code for pagename:

```
Router::connect('/:slug', array('controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'index'));
```

**UPDATE 1**

If you want to treat *www.example.com/user* as same as *www.example.com/users* then you need to add following, because CakePHP controller name is plural as per CakePHP naming convention:

```
Router::connect('/user/:action/*', array('controller' => 'users'));
```

**UPDATE 2**

`Router::connect(':slug')` overwrite all of default routing. So you need to use [custom routing class](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#custom-route-classes) as like as :

```
App::uses('SlugRoute', 'Routing/Route');

Router::connect(
    '/:slug',
    array('controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'index'),
    array('routeClass' => 'SlugRoute')
);
```

Comment: but for this to happen the URL will be 
www.example.com/Controller/
for a controller

www.example.com/Pagename
for a page

but i want the URL to be same 
www.example.com/Controller 
and
www.example.com/Pagename 
and still be handled correctly
from my all trials i dont think this can happen since there is no way to distinguish between "Controller" and "page" for the same URL